# AWSS3TransferUtilityMultiPartUploadTask - Progress value not updated returning from background

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, awss3transferutility

I'm using the AWS iOS SDK to upload files to S3. I am using `AWSS3TransferUtility` because I want to allow background uploads.

The background task is working - a large file can successfully upload while backgrounded. The issue is, when I bring my app back to the foreground, the `task.result.progress.fractionCompleted` value remains at the value from before being backgrounded. And if I foreground my app before the upload is complete, the progress value will remain at that value until it is done, then jump up to 1.0.

When the app comes back to the foreground, I call `enumerateToAssignBlocksForUploadTask:multiPartUploadBlocksAssigner:downloadBlocksAssigner:` on my TransferUtility class, and I reassign the progress and completion handlers.

Does anyone know what may cause that value not to update? I'm not sure how to resume updating my progress bar because of this. Thanks!

Edit: Here is where I start the upload process. I have a wrapper around the AWS Task that holds onto the progress and completion handlers.

```
func upload(storagePath: String, sourceURL: URL, _ progressCompletion: @escaping ProgressCompletionCallback)-> UploadTask {

    let expression = AWSS3TransferUtilityMultiPartUploadExpression()
    expression.progressBlock = {(task, progress) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            print("Progess: \(progress)")
            progressCompletion(false, Float(progress.fractionCompleted), nil)
        })
    }

    var completionHandler: AWSS3TransferUtilityMultiPartUploadCompletionHandlerBlock
    completionHandler = { (task, error) -> Void in
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            print("Completed!")
            progressCompletion(true, Float(task.progress.fractionCompleted), error)
        })
    }

    let awsTask = transferUtility.uploadUsingMultiPart(fileURL: sourceURL,
                                         bucket: Constants.bucketName,
                                         key: storagePath,
                                         contentType: "text/plain",
                                         expression: expression,
                                         completionHandler: completionHandler)

    return UploadTask(task: awsTask,
                      progressBlock: expression.progressBlock!,
                      completionBlock: completionHandler)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue when downloading files. [Here](https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios/issues/1143) is a link to the issue i opened on their github page, atleast for the case of downloading files. They don't receive callbacks from the `NSURLSession` class thats being used. It is probably something similar in your case.

Comment: I am facing the same issue as "Jake G" mentioned, but I am not using AWS. Any solution to get the progress of the background download task?

Comment: another observation, the progress working in Xcode simulator for the background downloads when we bring the app from background to foreground. The issue is only with the real device.